# http to https redirect - htaccess changes

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the below condition in my .htaccess file. I am trying to redirect http page to https. But no luck. not sure what's wrong below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirect http://mydomain.archinit.com/landing-page/ https://www.newdomain.com/insights/spotlight-on/landing-page
```

any help on how to fix this pls?

Comment: "But no luck" - so what happens exactly? That first rule is a "http to https redirect" - so it should at least do _something_. Do you have other rules in the `.htaccess` file? Where is the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Check if you _really_ enabled the interpretation of such files (see the `AllowOverride` directive), that this file is _really_ located inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of your http host (not any other host) and that is is actually readable for your http server process.

Answer (score 0):

### Location of `.htaccess`

Place your `.htaccess` file in the folder of your website (alongside `index.php`/`index.html`, etc.)! You don't have to do anything to run this. You just need to put it in the right place, next to the file called by the web server!

### Code to `.htaccess`

```
# Run this code IF "mod_rewrite" module was enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable server-side redirects
    RewriteEngine On

    # 1. Use SSL
    # Determine the condition when the rule should be applied
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # Execute the given rule if the condition written above it is true
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # 2. Detect old domain and redirect to new
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.archinit.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # 3. Detect old folder and redirect to new
    RewriteRule ^landing-page/(.+)$ /insights/spotlight-on/landing-page/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

### If still not working...

If it still doesn't work, then the problem is not with the .htaccess file, but with the server settings.

Without more information, I wouldn't start guessing.

Comment: But this is "identical" to the code posted in the question?!

Comment: Opss.. You're right. I was mistaken. Its last row messed me up. It makes no sense.